# Login not working in Opera Mini 3

Tags: support, login, mobile-web

I am using Opera Mini 3 (yes I know Opera Mini 7 is out) because, in Dubai, both major telecom operators have blocked Opera Mini 4+ or any other mobile application which is transmitting data over the Internet in encrypted form. Because, apparently, they cannot see what a user is browsing/seeing and thus cannot censor it. Opera Mini 4+ encrypts all the data to its Norway servers.

My employer does not permit any smart phones at work (don't know the reason). Nokia Series 60, Android, iPhone, all are considered to be smart phones. So, I am stuck with Nokia 6300 (Series 40). Its built in browser is very basic.

When I open the Stack Overflow site, and click *login* on the top bar, I get to the page saying *Click any of these to login*. On computers, it also displays the various options (StackExchange, Google, OpenID etc..) I think it is a jQuery element. On my phone it simply does not appear.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: have you tried [UCBrowser](http://www.ucweb.com/English/UCbrowser/index.html) ?

Comment: No, will try today. Also will give a shot to stackmobile.com

Comment: Maybe switching between mobile/full site helps? Which one are you seeing? (Click "mobile" or "full site" in the footer to activate and to return to the previous mode. The "full site" thing does not appear as a link in a regular browser, but you can click it anyway; don't know what your Opera will make of that.)

Comment: Arjan In mobile, Clicking on fullsite always returns to the same old mobile layout/version. @Lucifer Same thing with UCBrowser the three dots (loading) are appearing and nothing happens after that.

Comment: then try updating your phone's software could be the last option in your case as i would not like to suggest you to **change your company** :P

Comment: Naa I think I will try to visit SO only in the evenings from home.. :)

Comment: That would be nice option :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the switching *itself* might help. Just that maybe the login page might work in the other theme (mobile versus full, or the other way around)?

Comment: @arjan Nope, clicking on _fullsite_ never goes to actual full site. Always redirects to the same old mobile layout.. :(